# Can't Enforce password reset on WSo2IS?

Tags: simplesamlphp, wso2-identity-server

When I send the SOAP request to update the forcedpasswordreset value i get **202 Code** on the SOAP UI and the user doesn't get notified to update the password, and the wso2carbon.log says the following:

> INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'wso2admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2019-01-07 11:39:23,318+0200]

I'm trying to use *AdminForcedPasswordReset* in **WSO2 Identity Server** and I followed the steps in {https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Forced+Password+Reset} **RecoveryEmail** type.

Here's my SOAP Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mgt="http://mgt.profile.user.identity.carbon.wso2.org" xmlns:xsd="http://mgt.profile.user.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <mgt:setUserProfile>
        <mgt:username>omar.alaeldain</mgt:username>
        <mgt:profile>
            <xsd:fieldValues>
                <xsd:claimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/identity/adminForcedPasswordReset</xsd:claimUri>
                <xsd:fieldValue>true</xsd:fieldValue>
            </xsd:fieldValues>
            <xsd:profileName>default</xsd:profileName>
        </mgt:profile>
    </mgt:setUserProfile>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I expect the user omar.alaeldain to get nitified at next login by an E-mail to update his password.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify whether you have done the following changes.

1. You need to enable "Enable Password Reset via Recovery Email" from the below configuration.
   https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Forced+Password+Reset?preview=/60494003/60494255/forced-password-reset-residentidp.png
2. You need to configure "from email address".

Open the output-event-adapters.xml file found in the /repository/conf directory. 
Configure the relevant property values for the email server that you need to configure for this service under the  tag.

```
<adapterConfig type="email">
    <!-- Comment mail.smtp.user and mail.smtp.password properties to support connecting SMTP servers which use trust
    based authentication rather username/password authentication -->
    <property key="mail.smtp.from">abcd@gmail.com</property>
    <property key="mail.smtp.user">abcd</property>
    <property key="mail.smtp.password">xxxx</property>
    <property key="mail.smtp.host">smtp.gmail.com</property>
    <property key="mail.smtp.port">587</property>
    <property key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</property>
    <property key="mail.smtp.auth">true</property>
    <!-- Thread Pool Related Properties -->
    <property key="minThread">8</property>
    <property key="maxThread">100</property>
    <property key="keepAliveTimeInMillis">20000</property>
    <property key="jobQueueSize">10000</property>
</adapterConfig>
```

3. Configure email address to the user omar.alaeldain.

once finish all the three steps invoke the soap service.